# results of scipy.optimize minimize are off

Tags: python, function, optimization, scipy, minimization

Loading the data:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from scipy.special import lambertw
import math

filelist = []
coords=[]

r0 = 0.1095/2 #in um
v0 = 4/3*math.pi*r0**3
ci0 = 0.19
cs = (0.522-ci0)/2+ci0
cw = 55
vf = v0*ci0/(ci0 + cs)


i=0
for fname in glob("*.txt"):
    x,y = np.genfromtxt(fname, unpack=True)
    i+=1
    # normalize
    ynorm = ((y-min(y))/((np.mean(y[-200:]))-min(y)))
    coords.append([x,ynorm])
plt.show()

init_guess=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsvGF.png)

So far so good. The problem is, that the minimization of function ssvn, which should fit function intn with fitting parameters (rr, bsn, dsn, pf, pfn) to the curves shown above, leads to values that are totally off.

```
for n in range(0,i): 

    vol = lambda pf: vf*(1+lambertw((cs/ci0)*np.exp(cs/ci0-(3*pf*(ci0+cs)**2)*(coords[n][0])/(r0*ci0*cw))))
    voln = lambda pfn: vf*(1+lambertw((cs/ci0)*np.exp(cs/ci0-(3*pfn*(ci0+cs)**2)*(coords[n][0])/(r0*ci0*cw))))
    totv = lambda rr, pf, pfn: rr*vol(pf) + (1 - rr)*voln(pfn)
    ifin = np.mean(coords[n][1][-200:])
    asn = lambda bsn, dsn: ifin - bsn*vf + dsn*vf**2
    intn = lambda rr, bsn, dsn, pf, pfn: asn(bsn, dsn) + bsn*totv(rr, pf, pfn) + dsn*(totv(rr, pf, pfn))**2
    def ssvn(var):
        rr, bsn, dsn, pf, pfn = var
        return sum(coords[n][1] - ((intn(rr, bsn, dsn, pf, pfn))**2)[0])
    bnds = ((0, 1), (None, 0), (0,None), (0,100), (0,1000))
    result = (minimize(ssvn, init_guess, bounds=bnds, options={"maxiter":5000}))
    print(result.x)
```

I would appreciate so much getting a hint why the minimization doesn't work in this case!

Comment: Without knowing what is loaded with glob("*.txt") it is hard to say, since your example cannot be reproduced. Also if the "values that are totally off", what is the expected result? Could you include that?

Comment: Right! I've added the values.

Answer (score 0):

Sure! I have reduced the calculation above for a clearer interpretation of the fit to:

```
init_guess=[1, 1, 1]

for n in range(0,i): 

    vol = lambda pf: vf*(1+lambertw((cs/ci0)*np.exp(cs/ci0-(3*pf*(ci0+cs)**2)*(coords[n][0])/(r0*ci0*cw))))
    ifin = np.mean(coords[n][1][-200:])
    asn = lambda bsn, dsn: ifin - bsn*vf + dsn*vf**2
    intn = lambda bsn, dsn, pf: asn(bsn, dsn) + bsn*vol(pf) + dsn*(vol(pf))**2
    def ssvn(var):
        bsn, dsn, pf = var
        return sum(coords[n][1] - ((intn(bsn, dsn, pf))**2)[0])
    bnds = ((None, 0), (0,None), (0,100))
    result = (minimize(ssvn, init_guess, bounds=bnds, options={"maxiter":5000}))
    print(result.x)
    plt.plot(coords[n][0], (intn(result.x[0], result.x[1], result.x[2])))
```

some points of a simulated curve (loaded with glob(".txt")) are:

```
0. 0.000050914985470697376
0.1 0.00005226691119118905
0.2 0.000053273861157071714
0.3 0.00005399970642597728
0.4 0.000054509506785116066
0.5 0.000054860656948798976
0.6 0.00005509912334378207
0.7 0.00005525962182128574
0.8 0.000055366845246536884
0.9 0.0000554381500488244
1. 0.00005548540798339426
1.1 0.00005551666847593382
1.2 0.00005553732736787186
1.3 0.000055550957627270784
1.4 0.00005555995251553653
1.5 0.000055565880705824926
1.6 0.00005556979319469152
1.7 0.000055572367783992574
1.8 0.000055574071506690767
1.9 0.000055575203109605593
2. 0.000055575944218954186
```

and values to be expected are:
bsn ~ -0.037, dsn ~ 1.8e-05, pf ~ 7